# Replace and loop images after X milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting this to work, I just want the images to loop endlessly. What isn't right here?

```js
var croppingImages = new Array()
croppingImages[0] = "https://img.f1today.eu/x/topstory/58c7e187745517a1c90fc5ebe21c55da49223c999500b.jpg";
croppingImages[1] = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C69Y8aWW0AEkCIW.jpg:small";
setTimeout("animateImages()", 100);
var cropImg = 0;
    
function animateImages() {
  document.getElementById("cropping__animation").src = croppingImages[cropImg]
  x++;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.f1today.eu/x/topstory/58c7e187745517a1c90fc5ebe21c55da49223c999500b.jpg" id="cropping__animation">
```

Comment: You didn't define `x`. You call `animateImages` only once.

Comment: I added cropImg++, but it still didn't work :| @dfsq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here.

1) `cropImg` is never incremented, so `animateImages` will always show the same image

2) `animateImages` will only ever be called once by `setTimeout`

This code works better:

```
var cropImg = 0;
var croppingImages = new Array()

croppingImages[0] = "https://img.f1today.eu/x/topstory/58c7e187745517a1c90fc5ebe21c55da49223c999500b.jpg";
croppingImages[1] = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C69Y8aWW0AEkCIW.jpg:small";

animateImages();

function animateImages() {
  document.getElementById("cropping__animation").src = croppingImages[cropImg];

  if (++cropImg > croppingImages.length - 1)
  {
    cropImg = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    animateImages();
  }, 3000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6bhgm53/5/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop them endless you maybe should use setInterval() and not setTimeout(). Also you should make it that your cropImg variable loops by checking if the value is greater than the array length.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/y6bhgm53/6/

I hope it helps

```js
var croppingImages = new Array()
croppingImages[0] = "https://img.f1today.eu/x/topstory/58c7e187745517a1c90fc5ebe21c55da49223c999500b.jpg";
croppingImages[1] = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C69Y8aWW0AEkCIW.jpg:small";
setInterval(animateImages, 100);
var cropImg = 0;

function animateImages() {
  document.getElementById("cropping__animation").src = croppingImages[cropImg]
  cropImg++;
  if(cropImg>=croppingImages.length)cropImg=0
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.f1today.eu/x/topstory/58c7e187745517a1c90fc5ebe21c55da49223c999500b.jpg" id="cropping__animation">
```